# Different filters on different table columns

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I would like to create a table that the columns' data are formatted based on different filters.

Suppose I have an array object that looks like this:

```
$scope.components = [
                     {lastName:'Bob', firstName:'John',netWorth:1000},
                     {lastName:'Foo', firstName:'Bar',netWorth:2000}
                   ];
```

Now I would like to use `ng-repeat` to populate the data into the tables. Here is how I do it:

```
            <tr ng-repeat="component in components">
              <td ng-repeat="column in tableColumns">
                {{component[column]}}
              </td>
            </tr>
```

The `$scope.components` above is a simplistic example, but the main point is that I have such data objects that their properties are **consistent** but differ as according to the object. That is why I have a second `ng-repeat` that allows user to define what is inside `tableColumns`. In our case, `tableColumns` is an array of strings:  `$scope.tableColumns = ['lastName','firstName','netWorth']`.

The table behaves normally. The main problem is , how do I format each individual column using a particular filter? Say, for the first column of the table, i.e the `lastName`  property, I would want to format it  using `uppercase` filter, the second column of the table, i.e `firstName` property with `lowercase` filter, and last column `netWorth` property with `currency` filter.

My thought process will be something along this line:

```
<td ng-repeat="column in tableColumn>
  {{component[column] | filterArray}}
</td>
```

where `$scope.filterArray` is an array of string of the filters that I want, like `'uppercase'`,`'currency'`, etc. This array of string should go in the accordance of the elements in the tableColumn array too. For example, to get the desired formatting as mentioned above, I have to declare the `$scope.arrayFilter` as follows: `$scope.arrayFilter=['uppercase','lowercase','currency']`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can write own filter for that which will use `$filter` service.

So, your filter will be looking like this:

```
app.filter('custom', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
  return function (value, type) {
    return $filter(type)(value);
  }
}]);
```

Now you could use this one by next way: `{{value | custom : filterName}}`, for example:

```
{{component[column] | custom : 'uppercase'}}
```

Now you just need to create an object which will contain names of columns and its filters name, like this:

```
  $scope.filterArray = {
    'lastName': 'uppercase',
    'firstName': 'lowercase',
    'netWorth': 'currency'
  };
```

So now your HTML code will be looking like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="component in components">
  <td ng-repeat="column in tableColumns">{{component[column] | custom : filterArray[column]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Everything seems to be working in demo. Hope, this will help you.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/fE02ZmaUWxeG9h71TabO?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
<td ng-repeat="column in tableColumn>
  <label ng-if="column === 1">
     {{component[column] | uppercase}}
  </label>
  <label ng-if="column === 2">
     {{component[column] | lowercase}}
  </label>

...

</td>
```

or you can do it using an ordered arrayFilter like you said